# Tensorflow: NaNs propagating throughout network, even though using sparse_softmax etc

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

Solved, I had more targets that output neurons.

I believe something is going wrong with - now I think it's tensorflow's `sparse_softmax_cross....` function (- before: my data). I've written a simple program (3 lyr network) to try and see what is going on:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import h5py
import numpy as np

def ini_weight_var(shape):
     return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=(2.0/shape[0])**0.5))

def ini_bias_var(shape):
     return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=shape))

input_dim = 1287
input_lyr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_dim ])
targs = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None,])
w1 = ini_weight_var([input_dim ,2048])
b1 = ini_bias_var([2048])
a1 = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(input_lyr, w1) + b1)

w2 = ini_weight_var([2048, 2023])
b2 = ini_bias_var([2023])
out = tf.matmul(a1, w2) + b2
out_sm = tf.nn.softmax(out)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(out, targs))
get_acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal( tf.argmax(out_sm, 1), targs) ,"float"))
train_adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-10).minimize(cost)

d = h5py.File('data-amfb/amfb_train_subset.hdf5','r')
# shapes: f==(1000,1287); t==(1000,) -- types: f.dtype==np.float32; t.dtype==np.int64
f, t = d['feats'][()], d['targs'][()]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(2):
        logit = sess.run(out, feed_dict={input_lyr: f})
        sm_res = sess.run(out_sm, feed_dict={input_lyr: f})
        print("is 0 in logit: {}".format(bool(np.sum(logit==0)))) # For Da Tong.
        print("Smallest sm outputs: {}".format(np.sort(np.min(sm_res, axis=1))[:20]))           
        print("is logit with Nan: {}".format(bool(np.sum(np.isnan(logit)))))
        print("is sm with Nan: {}".format(bool(np.sum(np.isnan(sm_res)))))
        print "Performing backprop."
        sess.run(train_adam, feed_dict={input_lyr: f, targs: t})

        print("Score: {}".format(sess.run(get_acc, feed_dict={input_lyr: f, targs: t})))
        print("Cost: {}".format(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={input_lyr: f, targs: t})))
        print
```

Here the output (softmax values clearly not too small):

```
    is 0 in logit: False
Smallest sm outputs: [  4.24013763e-07   6.52373728e-07   7.47293313e-07   8.81291555e-07
   1.04935509e-06   1.05191452e-06   1.07265134e-06   1.08382812e-06
   1.11767417e-06   1.13135320e-06   1.16807541e-06   1.17315426e-06
   1.17497621e-06   1.20026777e-06   1.20443030e-06   1.20840150e-06
   1.21510743e-06   1.22574534e-06   1.24325027e-06   1.24601388e-06]
is logit with Nan: False
is sm with Nan: False
Performing backprop.
Score: 0.0340000018477
Cost: nan

is 0 in logit: False
Smallest sm outputs: [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
is logit with Nan: True
is sm with Nan: True
Performing backprop.
Score: 0.0340000018477
Cost: nan
```

I've checked `np.sum(np.isnan(w1).astype(np.int32))` and `np.sum(np.isnan(f).astype(np.int32))`, they both equal 0. So no NaNs in my data or in the weight matrix. Data has mean 0 and stddev 1.

(since changed my mind) I think the problem has to do with my data because it's only with this specific one where this problem occurs. If I use different data it works (other feature type); no nans.

I've tried all sensible variations of float32/64 and int32/64. And I've tried various learning rates and values for `epsilon`. I've also tried different weight inits.

Now I'm out of ideas.

Edit: I was printing out the hidden layer activations after having trained an epoch, this leads to the NaNs. If I print it out before everything is fine. So something is going wrong with `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

My logits are quite small. Don't know whether that means anything. Softmax should normalize everything.

Comment: Because cross entropy will do log calculation, if the input contains 0, the output will be `NaN`. Try to use `tf.Print`to log the value of `out`.

Comment: But then I'd have zeros in the softmax output, and my smallest value is far from 0. I tried it anyways by including `print("is 0 in logit: {}".format(bool(np.sum(logit==0))))`. No zeros. I don't like `tf.Print` because I can't just print stuff out, that wouldn't tell me anything (dimensions are too big to see all the values), I have to take the mean or min etc.

Comment: Could you give more details about `targs`, please? Since `out` has been excluded from suspect list, the only one left is `targs`.

Comment: From the code: `# shapes: f==(1000,1287); t==(1000,) -- types: f.dtype==np.float32; t.dtype==np.int64` -- `targs` is a list of target indices. Because I'm using `tf.nn.sparse_softmax...` I don't have to use one-hot encoded vectors as targets, I can simply input the indices (that's how that function works, without `sparse` your targets have to be one-hot encoded).

Comment: Well, if value of `targs` are all less then 0, the transformed one-hot matrix would be full of 0. So, just to make sure `targs` is valid. Try `tf.one_hot(targs, tf.reduce_max(targs))` and check whether `targs` values are greater than 0.

Comment: I got it. I had more target indices than I had output neurons (...what a silly mistake). Thank you for your help. You sent me in the right direction!

Comment: Grad to hear that!